# How to get an importance of a class using random forest?

Tags: variables, random-forest, decision-tree

I am using `randomForest` package in my dataset to do a classification, but with the `importance` command I only get the importance of variables. So, if I want the variable importance by specific categories of variables? Like a specific location in a region variable, how much that region impact in the total. I thought in transformer every class in a dummy, but i don't know if this is really a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "variable importance by specific categories of variables". That has not been implemented, but I guess it would be possible, meaningful and perhaps useful. Of course it would not be meaningful for variables with only two categories.

I would implement it something like:
Train model -> compute out-of-bag prediction performance (OOB-cv1) -> permute specific category by specific variable (reassign this category randomly to other categories, weighted by other category prevalence) -> re-compute out-of-bag- prediction performance (OOB-cv2) -> subtract OOB-cv1 from OOB-cv2

*And then I wrote the a function implementing categorical specific variable importance.*

```
library(randomForest)

#Create some classification problem, with mixed categorical and numeric vars
#Cat A of var 1, cat B of var 2 and Cat C of var 3 influence class the most.
X.cat = replicate(3,sample(c("A","B","C"),600,rep=T))
X.val = replicate(2,rnorm(600))
y.cat = 3*(X.cat[,1]=="A") + 3*(X.cat[,2]=="B") + 3*(X.cat[,3]=="C")
y.cat.err = y.cat+rnorm(600)
y.lim = quantile(y.cat.err,c(1/3,2/3))
y.class = apply(replicate(2,y.cat.err),1,function(x) sum(x>y.lim)+1)
y.class = factor(y.class,labels=c("ann","bob","chris"))  
X.full = data.frame(X.cat,X.val)
X.full[1:3] = lapply(X.full[1:3],as.factor)

#train forest
rf=randomForest(X.full,y.class,keep.inbag=T,replace=T)

#make function to compute crovalidated classification error
oobErr = function(rf,X) {
  preds = predict(rf,X,type="vote",predict.all = T)$individual
  preds[rf$inbag!=0]=NA
  oob.pred = apply(preds,1,function(x) {
    tabx=sort(table(x),dec=T)
    majority.vote = names(tabx)[1]
  })
  return(mean(as.character(rf$y)!=oob.pred))
}

#make function to iterate all categories of categorical variables
#and compute change of OOB class error due to permutation of category
catVar = function(rf,X,nPerm=2) {
  ref = oobErr(rf,X)
  catVars = which(rf$forest$ncat>1)
  lapply(catVars, function(iVar) {
    catImp = replicate(nPerm,{
      sapply(levels(X[[iVar]]), function(thisCat) {
        thisCat.ind = which(thisCat==X[[iVar]])
        X[thisCat.ind,iVar] = head(sample(X[[iVar]]),length(thisCat.ind))
        varImp = oobErr(rf,X)-ref
      })
    })
    if(nPerm==1) catImp else apply(catImp,1,mean) 
  })
}

#try it out
out = catVar(rf,X.full,nPerm=4)
print(out) #seems like it works as it should

$X1
      A       B       C 
0.14000 0.07125 0.06875 

$X2
         A          B          C 
0.07458333 0.16083333 0.07666667 

$X3
         A          B          C 
0.05333333 0.08083333 0.15375000
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but still not exactly what I want. I thought to use in a report, so I am in a need of a number for each category. would greatly facilitate the understanding of the people regarding the impact of every category.

Comment: well you could just repeat above schema for every category of every variable

Comment: wrote an R implementation computing categorical specific variable importance